# Find value ranges from ordered values without user defined variable?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have the following data:

| reported_date | value | validity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-25 | 34725.00 | 1 |
| 2021-02-26 | 34749.00 | 1 |
| 2021-02-27 | 34773.00 | 0 |
| 2021-02-28 | 34797.00 | 0 |
| 2021-03-01 | 34818.00 | 0 |
| 2021-03-02 | 34818.00 | 0 |
| 2021-03-07 | 34928.00 | 0 |
| 2021-03-08 | 34952.00 | 0 |
| 2021-03-09 | 34976.00 | 1 |
| 2021-03-10 | 35000.00 | 1 |

And I need to find *validity* date ranges, date borders (inclusive) where the validity value stays the same:

| begin_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-25 | 2021-02-26 |
| 2021-02-27 | 2021-03-08 |
| 2021-03-09 | 2021-03-10 |

I managed to obtain that result with a query like:

```
SELECT
    MIN(reported_date) AS begin_date,
    MAX(reported_date) AS end_date
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        reported_date,
        validity,
        @valgrp := (
        CASE
            WHEN MOD(@valgrp, 100) != validity THEN @valgrp + 100 - MOD(@valgrp, 100) + validity
            WHEN @valgrp IS NULL THEN 100 + validity
            ELSE @valgrp
        END ) AS validity_group
    FROM
        ...
    WHERE
        ... ) v
GROUP BY
    validity_group
```

But this relies on a user-defined variable, that [according to the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) may be future-proof:

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a
> user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is
> supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to
> removal in a future release of MySQL.

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Window functions can be used to replace this use of a user variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions `LAG()` and `SUM()` to create groups of the rows with the same consecutive `validity` and then get the min and max dates of each group:

```
SELECT MIN(reported_date) begin_date,   
       MAX(reported_date) end_date
FROM (       
  SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY reported_date) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COALESCE(validity <> LAG(validity) OVER (ORDER BY reported_date), 1) flag
    FROM tablename
  ) t 
) t  
GROUP BY grp
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0e561f9a363c010c102ec4890eee087).